# Rotary dial connected to gpio pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

How does one convert the pulses of the rotary dial into digits using python? Right now the code below will print the number of pulses it is receiving from the rotary dial. So dialing 2 on the rotary dial prints two "1+ 1+". Dialing 3 on the rotary dial prints three "1+ 1+ 1+" and so on.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import math, sys, os
import subprocess
import socket

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

c=0
last = 1

def count(pin):
    global c 
    c = c + 1

GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH)

while True:
    try:
        if GPIO.event_detected(18):
            current = GPIO.input(18)
            if(last != current):
                if(current == 0):
                    GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.BOTH, callback=count, bouncetime=5)
                else:
                    GPIO.remove_event_detect(23)    
                    print "1+"
                last = GPIO.input(18)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

How would you go about giving each number on the rotary dial its own function? Like dialing 1 unlocks the front door "GPIO.output(26, True)". Dialing 2 opens the garage door "GPIO.output(27, True)".

```
if dial 1:
  GPIO.output(26, True)
  print "Door unlocked"

if dial 2:
  GPIO.output(27, True)
  print "Garage Open"

if dial 3:
  print "Open slot"

if dial 4:
  print "Open slot"
```

This is clearly not python but how could something similar be done?

Comment: Use a dict and sum the pulses mapping numbers to actions

Comment: Is it possible to get an example?

Answer (score 1):

Not overly familiar with the Pi but you can map actions to keys in a dict, instead of printing the pulses save how many there are then use the count to call access the appropriate GPIO call:

```
d = {1:lambda: GPIO.output(26, True), 2: lambda: GPIO.output(27, True), 3:lambda : GPIO.output(28, True)}
GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH)
var = 0
flag = False

while True:
    try:
        if GPIO.event_detected(18):
            current = GPIO.input(18)
            if last != current:
                flag = True
                if current == 0:
                    GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.BOTH, callback=count, bouncetime=5)
                else:
                    GPIO.remove_event_detect(23)
                    var += 1
                last = GPIO.input(18)
            elif flag:
                d[var]()
                var = 0
                flag = False
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

I am presuming that when last is equal to current the pulse has ended, I set a flag so you don't keep setting the pin to on if nothing is happening

Comment: All tho more information/examples are welcome, this is enough information for me to pice together a fully functional script. Thanks. I will post the script when its fully working.

Comment: No worries, I am not familiar enough with GPIO to give a definitive answer but the logic should be very close to the code above, the main thing is to capture the pulses in a variable and do the appropriate call using the key.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give a shoutout to my good friend Bob for getting this python script working. At the same time I don't want to give a shoutout to Obama for doing absolutely nothing to help make this work.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(18, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_UP)


num = 0
prnt = 0
last = 0

while True:
    input_value = gpio.input(18)

    if (input_value == 1) and (input_value != last):
        last = 1
        prnt = 1
        num += 1
        time.sleep(0.05)
        continue

    if (input_value == 0) and (input_value != last):
        last = 0
        time.sleep(0.05)
        continue

    if (input_value == 0) and (input_value == last):
        if (prnt == 1):
            if (num == 10):
                num = 0

            if (num == 0):
                print("a")
            if (num == 1):
                print("b")                
            if (num == 2):
                print("c")
            if (num == 3):
                print("d")
            if (num == 4):
                print("e")                
            if (num == 5):
                print("f")                
            if (num == 6):
                print("g")                
            if (num == 7):
                print("h")                
            if (num == 8):
                print("i")                
            if (num == 9):
                print("jklmnopqrstuvwxyz")                


            num = 0
            prnt = 0
            last = 0
        continue
```